# Azure - SSMS - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, ssms, azure-hdinsight

I am working through my first Azure HDInsight tutorial.  Can I do this without installing Azure Remote PowerShell on my local computer?

Can I use SSMS (2008R2) to run the PowerShell?  My first attempt at that led me down the path of using a Database in Azure, but I do not think that is what I want to do (the tutorial describes setting Storage (not a Database) and then an HDInsight instance to interact with that Storage).

I am doing this tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/get-started-hdinsight/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use SQL Server and HDInsight together as part of a full pipeline, for the purposes of the getting started tutorial you want to think of them as two very different things.

The Storage referred to, is a standard Windows Azure Storage account, based on blobs. These then form a backing file system for the HDInsight cluster.

As far as using PowerShell goes, it is definitely the best, and easiest way to submit jobs to an HDInsight cluster. I would also recommend using a regular PowerShell console, or the PowerShell ISE to work with HDInsight as well, rather than the one available through SSMS, since the SSMS version won't load all the Azure modules by default.

There are other ways to submit jobs if PowerShell is not your thing (if you are on OS X or Linux for instance). You can use the REST API provided by WebHCAT ([documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference)). If you're on Windows, and prefer C# to PowerShell, you can also use the Windows Azure HDInsight Management Client from the Microsoft Hadoop SDK to submit jobs (available on [codeplex](https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight/)). These will need you to break out Visual Studio and write a short console program to submit your job, so may be a bit heavy unless you're doing full on C# streaming Map Reduce, and so are already there.

If you're after a GUI based approach to job submission to HDInsight, you're out of luck at the moment, but your might like to check out what my team is working on at [Red Gate](http://bigdata.red-gate.com/), which will help you with submitting Hive and Pig jobs.